# Смена свойств элемента в зависимости от нажатаго элемента хтмл

Tags: javascript, html, функции, button

Друзья, такая вот проблема:
Есть 3 элемента див: див1, див2 и див3. В див1 и див2 есть 2 копки (б1,б2,б3,б4), в див3 есть 1 кнопка (б5).
По умолчанию: див2 и див 3 скрыты свойством visibility, а див1 виден.
С помощью кнопок б1 и б2 соответственно в див1 и див2 состояния видимости между див1 и див2 можно менять на противоположные, а кнопка б3 и б4 позволяет сделать невидимыми див1 и див2 и видимым див3.
А дальше моя проблема: мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку б5, скрывался див3 и становился видимым тот див (див1 или див2), который сделал див3 видимым.
Я рассуждал следующим образом: необходимо запомнить кнопку, на которую нажали, чтобы сделать див3 видимым, а затем, когда нажмут б5, будет произведен соответствующий обмен свойствами. Но в результате, запускается всегда див1.

Вот код:

хтмл:

```
<div id="d1" style="visibility: active;">
<p><button id="b1" onclick="fun11()">1.1</botton></p>
<p><button id="b2" onclick="fun12()">1.2</botton></p>
</div>
<div id="d2" style="visibility: hidden;">
<p><button id="b3" onclick="fun21()">2.1</botton></p>
<p><button id="b4" onclick="fun12()">2.2</botton></p>
</div>
<div id="d3" style="visibility: hidden;">
<p><button id="b5" onclick="fun3()">3</botton></p>
</div>
```

js

```
function fun11() {
document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun12() {
document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('d3').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun21() {
document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun3() {
document.getElementById('d3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
If (document.getElementById('b2').onclick = true) {
document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'visible';
} 
elseif (document.getElementById('b4').onclick = true) {
document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
}
```

Итак, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение на свой вопрос. Для этого пришлось использовать метод Element.closest()
На первую кнопку вешаем условие с проверкой самого первого родительского элемента. Если он соответствует заданному id (в моем случае), присваиваем заданной переменной некое значение (например, 1).
Затем, во второй просто проверяем значение заданной переменной и по заданному результату выполняем возвращение в див1 или див2. Данную функцию можно расширять, если элементов будет больше.

```
let parentId;

function fun11() {
    document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun12(el) {
    document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d3').style.visibility = 'visible';
    if (el.closest('#b2')) {
    parentId = 1;
  } else if (el.closest('#b4')) {
    parentId = 2;
  }
}

function fun21() {
    document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun3() {
    document.getElementById('d3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    if (parentId == 1) {
    document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'visible';}
    else if (parentId == 2) {
    document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'visible';}
}
```

```
<div id="d1" style="visibility: active;">
<p><button id="b1" onclick="fun11()">1.1</botton></p>
<p><button id="b2" onclick="fun12()">1.2</botton></p>
</div>
<div id="d2" style="visibility: hidden;">
<p><button id="b3" onclick="fun21()">2.1</botton></p>
<p><button id="b4" onclick="fun12()">2.2</botton></p>
</div>
<div id="d3" style="visibility: hidden;">
<p><button id="b5" onclick="fun3()">3</botton></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного переписал ваш вариант

```js
let parentId;

function fun11() {
    document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun12(el) {
    document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d3').style.visibility = 'visible';
    parentId = el.parentNode.id;
}

function fun21() {
    document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun22(el) {
    document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d3').style.visibility = 'visible';
    parentId = el.parentNode.id;
}

function fun3() {
    document.getElementById('d3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById(parentId).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```html
<div id="d1" style="visibility: active;">
    <button id="b1" onclick="fun11()">1.1</button>
    <button id="b2" onclick="fun12(this)">1.2</button>
</div>
<div id="d2" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <button id="b3" onclick="fun21()">2.1</button>
    <button id="b4" onclick="fun22(this)">2.2</button>
</div>
<div id="d3" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <button id="b5" onclick="fun3()">3</button>
</div>
```

Upd: если кнопки находятся в теге абзаца

```
<script>
let parentId;

function fun11() {
    document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun21() {
    document.getElementById('d2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun12() {
    let d1 = document.getElementById('d1');
    parentId = d1.id; d1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d3').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun22() {
    let d2 = document.getElementById('d2');
    parentId = d2.id; d2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('d3').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function fun3() {
    document.getElementById('d3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById(parentId).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
</script>

<div id="d1" style="visibility: visible;">
    <p><button id="b1" onclick="fun11()">1.1</button></p>
    <p><button id="b2" onclick="fun12()">1.2</button></p>
</div>
<div id="d2" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <p><button id="b3" onclick="fun21()">2.1</button></p>
    <p><button id="b4" onclick="fun22()">2.2</button></p>
</div>
<div id="d3" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <p><button id="b5" onclick="fun3()">3</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: а как это можно реализовать, если это не родительский элемент... например кнопка дополнительно находится теге абзаца <p>?

Comment: TemirStack, простите, но только заметил свои недочеты при постановке проблемы. 1. У меня одна функция на две кнопки. 2. Копки находятся не в самом диве, а в его элементах... Только что внес все правки в свой код-вопрос. Как бороться с этим?

Comment: drako black, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, это может быть полезным на будущее. Но Вы не учли втрое мое замечание о том, что функция одна для двух кнопок. В Вашем примере у каждой кнопки своя функция. И тем не менее, Вы сильно помогли мне в решении моей проблемы. Еще раз спасибо!